# How to pass schema prefix to queries that don't contain it

Tags: sql-server, schema

I have a bunch of SQL queries that don't have a schema prefix. Without the prefix, the queries won't run.

I wonder if there is a way to apply a schema to a query, without manually adding -- e.g., copying and pasting -- the schema prefix to each query. The prefix is the same for all the queries.

Also just to add, I use MS SQL Server. Thanks!

### EDIT

I am adding a sample query as requested.

The queries are basically like

```
   USE   DBID1000

SELECT   T1.USERID
  FROM   TABLE1 AS T1 WITH (NOLOCK)
  JOIN   TABLE2 AS T2 ON T1.NAME = T2.NAME
```

However, this won't run unless I add a schema prefix as shown below (assume the prefix is `dbdbo`

```
   USE   DBID1000

SELECT   T1.USERID
  FROM   dbdbo.TABLE1 AS T1 WITH (NOLOCK)
  JOIN   dbdbo.TABLE2 AS T2 ON T1.NAME = T2.NAME
```

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you mean. When you say 'queries', do you just mean bits of ad hoc SQL? Stored procedures? Something else? When you say they won't run without the schema prefix, what do you mean? Do you want to update some SQL text such that all database objects referenced are done so with their full (schema-including) name?

Comment: schemas are containers of objects.  Somebody intentionally created a container, called it dbdbo, and put some table objects in it.  If users want to query those tables they need to specify the schema object.  This is not magic, it is working as intended.  If you want the tables to be accessable to everyone without having to specify the schema, then create them under the DBO schema and make sure the users have access.  When queries run that do not specify a schema, SQL will check the DBO schema to see if the objects are there.

Answer (score 2):

Set the default schema for the user to the schema that your queries need to use.

```
ALTER USER [UserName] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[SchemaName]
```

Comment: If I use Windows authentication to connect to the SQL Server, is there a way that your solution can accommodate that? More specifically, is there a way to do `ALTER USER...` such that if the same query is given to another person, she won't have to change the `[UserName]` part

Comment: UserName can be a SQL account or a Windows account. It's specifically the user inside the database and not the login. A group can also have a default schema.

Answer (score 1):

One option (using the example you provided with schema dbdbo), is to map a new user to the database that contains the tables in question and make the default schema for that user dbdbo.  Then either connect as that user or execute as login for that user